# Add custom form in magento create order page

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-options, forms

How do I add a custom form in the magento create order page like the following ?

[image]

Comment: where you want to add your custom form?

Comment: In the backend. Under Sales/Order->Create new order. Ideally where i placed it in the image. Look at Edit Order. This is where id like my custom form to be.

Comment: I've tried adding a custom .phtml file under design/adminhtml/../../sales/order/create/myfile.phtml and creating a block under sales.xml in the layout but i cant get it to show. Some more guidance on how to achieve this would be nice.

Comment: Anyone guide me how can i integrate Custom Feedback Form Code Into Magento -  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334